# Using Multiple Web Adaptors ArcGIS-Server 10.2

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-web-adaptor

Currently we have a brand spanking new install of 10.2 ArcGIS-Server with the web adaptor installed on a separate server in the DMZ running HTTPS with a purchase SSL cert. We cannot bind both 80 and 443 on the IIS server as it breaks the applications using the SSL for some reason.

We need to install a second on another web server for a 3rd party app that integrates GIS web mapping into its software but cannot do HTTPS, so this will be Web Adaptor #2 using only http 80. Has anyone ever done multiple web adaptors? Are there any caveats to this?

Comment: Can be done but you need different ports open http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/install-guides/arcgis-server-web-adaptor-iis/10.1/index.html#//01nz0000000w000000 video http://video.arcgis.com/watch/1346/installing-the-arcgis-web-adaptor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to successfully do this with little to no issue. I installed the adapter for HTTP traffic on another server, while leaving our original HTTPS web adaptor untouched on the first web server.

Our firewall was setup to route traffic to each sub-url www.example.com/arcgis/map and /arcgis2/map according to protocol. Worked like a charm.